# How to set up a Model correctly?

Tags: magento-1.9, model

I want to create a Model that could be called from another extension. 
The tutorials I've found so far are quite confusing and I couldn't get it to work.

What is the minimum I need to do to make a fully functional model?

I have setup a simple module.
`config.xml` with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Jurgis_Checkoutstep>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    
        </Jurgis_Checkoutstep>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <Checkoutstep>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Jurgis_Checkoutstep</module>
                    <frontName>Checkoutstep</frontName>
                </args>
            </Checkoutstep>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Path: `/app/code/local/Jurgis/Checkoutstep/etc/config.xml`

Let's say I want to have a Model called `deliverydate.php` in:
`app/code/local/Jurgis/Checkoutstep/Model`

What do I need to add to `config.xml` and `deliverydate.php` (anywere else?) to create a working Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Jurgis_Checkoutstep>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    
        </Jurgis_Checkoutstep>
    </modules>
    ...
    <global>
        <models>
            <jurgis_checkoutstep>
                <class>Jurgis_Checkoutstep_Model</class>
            </jurgis_checkoutstep>
        </models>
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

Then create PHP file `app/code/local/Jurgis/Checkoutstep/Model/Deliverydate.php` with your model.

When you need to call it you can use:

```
Mage::getModel('jurgis_checkoutstep/deliverydate');
```

or

```
Mage::getSingleton('jurgis_checkoutstep/deliverydate');
```

Depending if you need a new instance or a singleton model.

Your model class will look like this:

```
<?php
class Jurgis_Checkoutstep_Model_Deliverydate
{
...
// your methods here
...
}
```

There is no need to inerith from `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` unless your are creating a datamodel representing a database object.

Comment: Will try! But if in the `Deliverydate.php` I want to include `class xxx_xxx extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` what should the `xxx_xxx` be replaced with?

Comment: `Jurgis_Checkoutstep_Model_Deliverydate`?

Comment: See my updated post

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the below example ..

```
   <global>
    <!-- ... -->
    <models>
        <weblog>
            <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model</class>
            <!--
            need to create our own resource, can't just
            use core_resource
            -->
            <resourceModel>weblog_resource</resourceModel>
        </weblog>
    </models>
    <!-- ... -->
</global>
```

The outer  tag is your Group Name, which should match your module name.  is the BASE name all Models in the weblog group will have, also calles Class Prefix. The  tag indicates which Resource Model that weblog group Models should use. There's more on this below, but for now be content to know it's your Group Name, followed by a the literal string "resource".

Ref URL : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html